# JBoss subsystem remoting and ejb3 error WFLYCTL0013

Tags: java-8, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, remoting

When I try to deploy my JBoss based Java application, my application is failing deployment due to the below errors.

**My application is running on JDK8 and JBoss 7.4.13**

I do have subsystem remoting and ejb3 in my standalone.
ejb
*Also one issue I noticed was that when I deployed it on a server having JBoss 7.4.12 no errors were coming. Only when I use JBoss 7.4.13, these errors occur*

`ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([`
`("subsystem" => "remoting"), ("http-connector" => "http-remoting-connector") ]) - failure description: { "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-remoting-connector is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default]"] }`

`ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "ejb3")]) - failure description: {`
`"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.remoting.connector.http-remoting-connector"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb.association is missing [org.wildfly.remoting.connector.http-remoting-connector]"] }`

`ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([`
`("subsystem" => "ejb3"), ("service" => "remote") ]) - failure description: { "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.remoting.connector.http-remoting-connector"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb.remote.client-mappings.http-remoting-connector is missing [org.wildfly.remoting.connector.http-remoting-connector]"] }`

`WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:`
`service jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default (missing) dependents: [service jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-remoting-connector] service org.wildfly.remoting.connector.http-remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb.association, service jboss.ejb.remote.client-mappings.http-remoting-connector]  WFLYCTL0448: 84 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed`

I did find similar queries posted on redhat forums however it requires us to take subscription for viewing those posts.

Can someone please help me out with this? I have been working on this quiet some time but no luck.